# Как получить спомощью jQuery доступ к форме которую вернул ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Как получить  с помощью jQuery доступ к форме которую вернул ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $(document).on('click',"#ggg",function()
{
 
});
```